# Placement additional menu on video website; top, bottom or something else

Tags: website-design, menu, placement

A friend of mine is building a video website where you can watch user submitted videos. Those videos are of individuals speaking their dream in the camera. The *focus* is on letting people watch those videos. *Additionally* people can 1) read the background information 'about' this website, and 2) submit their own video (which will first be evaluated by a redaction).

The design now is quite easy in one column, with a logo, and the videos under that in one list, one video horizontaly. My friend questions where the additional links could best be placed.

- **On top**, under the logo, before the videos.
- **In the footer**, at the end of the videos.
- **Somewhere else**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Jon said, putting them up top is standard and pretty much all users will be comfortable with this.

There's nothing wrong with putting them in the footer as well, but people won't expect links to only be in the footer.

I would avoid using a vertical menu unless space doesn't allow for horizontal, because that intrudes on your video watching area.

Answer (score 1):

The focus is on the videos, yes, but these menu items are actually important.

If he places them in the footer, they will be out of sight for users and they will be confused when they desire to take other actions (learn more, upload, etc)

Putting them at the top is standard and you wont lose points there, however I would suggest a 2 column (20%, 80%).